# Need to modify values across rows according to a condition

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I am cleaning my data with R and I want to change the values across a group of variables according to one condition that applies to all the values of each case for this group of variables

I have 4 that have three possible answers: "Yes", "No" and NA. I need to recode the values of some cases that right now are introduced as NA and I want to them to be introduced as No

Those cases that, across the 4 variables have NA's and 1, but no "0", I want to convert the NA's to "0". While in those cases where 1, 0 and Na coexist, I want to leave the NA's like that.

For instance, I have created this data.frame

```
A = c(1,0,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,1,1)
B = c(1,0,1,1,1,NA,1,1,0,0,1)
C = c(0,0,NA,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
D = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)

data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

Which looks like this: In this case, I would like to make a formula that changes the NA values of the third case for 0. Not simply recording the third case but as a function that I can apply to a database with thousands of cases... How could I do this?

```
    A  B  C D
1   1  1  0 0
2   0  0  0 0
3   1  1 NA 1
4  NA  1  1 0
5  NA  1  0 1
6  NA NA  0 0
7  NA  1  1 0
8   1  1  1 1
9   0  0  1 0
10  1  0  0 1
11  1  1  1 1
```

I have tried to do recoding, for loop and filters but I haven't got it right.

Perhaps a rowwise with a mutate could work?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's the logic for changing NA to 0 for that particular case?

Comment: There are some cases where we have identified that the NA's are in fact 0's

Comment: Ok, but you can't create a function that automates this without a logic.

Comment: The logic is that those cases were across the 4 variables have NA's and 1, but no "0", I want to convert the NA's to "0". While in those cases where 1, 0 and Na coexist on the 4-variable séquence,  I want to leave the NA's like that. Also, if in the 4-variable séquence there are 0 and NA's but no 1's, I do not want to transform the NA's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I somehow missed the explanation:

```
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(check_0 = sum(if_else(c_across(A:D) == 0, 1, 0, missing = 0))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(across(A:D, ~ if_else(check_0 == 0 & is.na(.x), 0, .x))) |> 
  select(-check_0)

# A tibble: 11 × 4
       A     B     C     D
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     0
 2     0     0     0     0
 3     1     1     0     1
 4    NA     1     1     0
 5    NA     1     0     1
 6    NA    NA     0     0
 7    NA     1     1     0
 8     1     1     1     1
 9     0     0     1     0
10     1     0     0     1
11     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. It says: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x `false` must be a double vector, not a character vector.

Comment: I can't replicate this error with the data you have provided and the code I put together. There must be something else going on in your data to cause this. What gets returned from `str(data)`?

Comment: It seems that your current data is set to character instead of numeric, you'll need to change your data to numeric in order for it to work.